# Order of phrases after verb:  Prefer "share with you X" or "share X with you"?

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis

Which of these sentences is grammatically correct?

1. I wanted to share with you the outcomes of today's board meeting
2. I wanted to share the outcomes of today's board meeting with you

Answer (score 3):

*Share, discuss,* and *explain* -- and possibly other transitive communication verbs -- have direct objects but don't take an indirect object like *tell*, so they can't do normal [*Goal Advancement*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html) (also known as *Dative Alternation, Dative Movement,* or just *Dative*), which exchanges the position of the indirect and direct objects, and loses *to*:

- *Bill brought the book **to** Mary.* ~ *Bill brought Mary the book.*
- *Bill told the story **to** Mary* ~ *Bill told Mary the story*.

One of the purposes of Goal Advancement is to move heavy NPs to the end of the sentence (there are a lot of rules that do this in English -- *[Extraposition](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/extrapos.html)* and [There-*Insertion*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/thereins.vbs.html) are examples), but without an indirect object one must use prepositions to indicate the addressee.

However, Goal Advancement has extensions for certain cases, and this seems to be one. For instance, a benefactive *for* phrase can be added to any volitional sentence:

- *I bought the book **for** Mary.* ~ *I bought Mary the book.*

and, provided that the recipient (*Mary*) winds up possessing the direct object (*the book*), this works. If this is not true, however, it doesn't:

- *I changed the tire **for** Mary,* **but not** **[I changed Mary the tire](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299).*

(i.e, I didn't transfer the tire to Mary by changing it)

In these cases, informational transfer happens, but these are not benefactive, and the verbs use different prepositions to indicate addressee/recipient, so the prepositions have to remain. But they can switch position with the direct object. Similarly,

- *He shared the poll results with you.* ~ *He shared **with you** the poll results.*
- *He discussed the poll results with you.* ~ *He discussed **with you** the poll results.*
- *He explained the poll results to you.* ~ *He explained **to you** the poll results.*

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically valid.

However, the first one uses a slightly unusual word order.

So

> I wanted to share the outcomes of today's board meeting with you.

... is to be preferred.

The key to getting this kind of thing right is to look at what native speakers write and say, and copy their sentence structures.

Comment: They're both equally grammatical, and if anything, the first is to be preferred because the heavy noun phrase is at the end of the sentence, where it's easier to parse.

Comment: Agreed.  Also it's preferred because the object is closer to the verb.  I want to share X with you.  X goes with share.

Comment: It's just a matter of how many words we're comfortable to have separating *"share"* and *"with"*. It would be an unusual word order if the thing shared was more concise - *"I wanted to share with you this joke"*, for example, sounds decidedly odd to me. Equally weird would be *"I wanted to share the outcome of the board meeting I had with Tom, Dick, and Harry in London last Wednesday afternoon with you"*.

Comment: Even worse: _*I shared with Bill it,_ _*I gave Bill it,_ _*I told Bill it._ Pronouns make the rules go bouncy.